# iOS 8 -- Capture Screen Video

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation, video-capture

I am trying to capture the on-screen activity of my app as a video (one that I can save/upload to Youtube).

There are many others who want to do this. Although the answers are generally sparse, there's no in-depth explanation of **how** to do this or **why** it can't be done.

1. There's a paid (and possibly sketchy?) option [here](http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-screen-capture-view/1038).
2. There's this related, but again, not totally clear SO answer about taking lots of screenshots: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501206/ios-drawing-screen-video-capture-not-smooth?rq=1).
3. There's a Smule app called MadPad HD that "records" the user's actions and stitches them together (but it doesn't actually capture the screen, it just stitches actions together). Here's the output of a stitching: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w1iQD6_0-4).

My questions are as follows:

1. Is capturing the video output of the screen and turning it into video actually **possible**?
2. If not, is taking lots of screenshots and turning them into video **feasible** (performance-wise)?
3. If 1 and 2 are not true, is this impossible because of **device constraints** or because **Apple doesn't want it**?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert on the matter, in fact I could be totally wrong. Wouldn't it be more practical, instead of capturing a video on the screen and then having to render it and use it, to just have a way to track the actions of what you are trying to record and to replay it. For example if you wanted to record a ball moving across the screen, instead of capturing a video, to just redo the same simulation and make it look like a video, however it's just the code executing the same exact thing again

Comment: [An Alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523622/how-can-i-run-record-an-ios-app-in-the-xcode-6-ios-simulator)

Comment: @RyanTemple -- How would I then take that series of actions, turn it into a video, and upload it to Youtube?

Comment: @the_UB -- The ability to create video needs to be available to the user, natively on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've already found an answer for this, but I thought I'd answer if anyone else is interested: with iOS 9 this will, of course, be possible through the new [ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=605) by Apple. But if you need it sooner (and with backwards compatibility) there are a couple of alternatives that I know of: [Kamcord](https://www.kamcord.com) and [Everyplay](https://developers.everyplay.com). Both lets your users record video and share through multiple channels, YouTube included. Both should be Sprite-Kit compatible and easily integrated (at least according to their websites!). Hope this helps!